# Warning: No emulator specified, defaulting to "avd_name"

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to start the emulator to test my project. I created three AVD's named `Nexus`, `Xperia`, and `Grand`. Then, in the Node Js I entered the command `cordova run android --emulator`. After build successful its shows this message. `WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Grand`. And then emulator starts with Grand.

My question is how I can set the default AVD name? Like, now I want to set the Xperia or Nexus to be default. I know it should be some simple thing to do, but I tried to search many posts even cant find the correct answer for my question.

Answer (score 27):

cordova "run" - will try to run it on a real device, if it's not found it fallback to "emulator" and it chooses the default because you didn't specified anything else.

Maybe you can still pass it the "--target" flag and it will fallback to the specified emulator name you created.

```
cordova run --target=name_of_your_emulator android
```

Or if you're intending to test on an emulator, then use the "emulate" instead of "run" option

```
cordova emulate --target=name_of_your_emulator android
```

Comment: Thanks! My app wouldn't on emulator without specifying a target!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 'WARNING : no emulator specified'. For everyone that need more help with this issue. Make sure you do following things:

- You have a 'platform-tools' and 'tools' directory in your AppData
- All requirements are installed. Check it with: "$ cordova requirements"
- Your Android Studio is open
- Your Android Virtual Device is booted and ready
- you use the command '$ cordova run --emulator'

There are some things I did for troubleshooting:

1. I created a new Device with Android 9 or 10
2. I used 'Wipe Data' and 'Cold boot' in the android device itself

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all the advice, solutions mentioned here, but no luck for me. After a while, I found that I needed to revoke the USB debugging authorization. Simply turning USB debugging on and off did not help.

Revoke the USB debugging authorization can be accessed in the developer options on the device. (On Samsung).